# Open cv chessBoard and 2d pieces recognition

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm doing a project in open cv.
The goal is to recognize 2d chess pieces on a chessboard,and their location.
the algorithm goes like this:

1. run canny on the picture.
2. run houghLines on the image.
   3.Merge close lines
   4.sort to vertical lines and horizontal lines.
   5.sort the lines and choose all the boarder lines +1 (so we get the actual play board lines and not the board lines)
3. find intersection of boarder lines. (4 corners)
4. do Homography with found corners.
5. split new image to 8X8 cells (length/8,width/8).
6. detect pieces on board and location using template matching.

Right now I'm stuck on doing the Homography. 
1. Sometimes I will detect the lines of the outer board , Sometimes I wont , and sometimes I will detect 2 lines on the outer board. 
2.the merge line function I found online seems not to be doing a good job. there can be 2 vertical lines on each other which it does not merge.

```
void processChessboardImage(Mat & image)
{
    Vec2f  temp(0,0);
    vector<Vec2f> lines;
    vector<Vec2f> boarderLines;
    vector<Vec2f> verticalLines;
    vector<Vec2f> horizontalLines;
    Mat canny_output,hough_output;

    canny_output = CannyOnImage(image);

    //cvtColor(canny_output, image, CV_GRAY2BGR);
    HoughLines(canny_output, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 120, 0, 0 );

    //at this point we have lines - all straight lines in image
    MergeRelatedLines(&lines,canny_output);

    for(int i=0; i< lines.size(); i++)
    {
        if(lines[i][1] != -100)
        {
            if((lines[i][1] >= 0 && lines[i][1] < 1 )|| lines[i][1] >= 3)//Vertical
            {
                verticalLines.push_back(lines[i]);
            }
            else // horizontal;
            {
                horizontalLines.push_back(lines[i]);
            }
        }
    }



    sort(verticalLines.begin(),verticalLines.end(),[](const Vec2f& elem1, const Vec2f& elem2){ return elem1[0]*cos(elem1[1]) < elem2[0]*cos(elem2[1]); });
    sort(horizontalLines.begin(),horizontalLines.end(),[](const Vec2f& elem1, const Vec2f& elem2){ return elem1[0] < elem2[0]; });

    int numVerticalLines = verticalLines.size();
    int numHorizontalLines = horizontalLines.size();


    boarderLines.push_back(verticalLines[0]);
    boarderLines.push_back(verticalLines[verticalLines.size()-1]);

    boarderLines.push_back(horizontalLines[0]);
    boarderLines.push_back(horizontalLines[horizontalLines.size() -1 ]);

void MergeRelatedLines(vector<Vec2f> *lines, Mat &img)
{
    vector<Vec2f>::iterator current;
    vector<Vec4i> points(lines->size());

    for(current=lines->begin();current!=lines->end();current++)
    {

        if((*current)[0]==0 && (*current)[1]==-100)
            continue;

        float p1 = (*current)[0];
        float theta1 = (*current)[1];

        Point pt1current, pt2current;
        if(theta1>CV_PI*45/180 && theta1<CV_PI*135/180)
        {
            pt1current.x=0;
            pt1current.y = p1/sin(theta1);

            pt2current.x=img.size().width;
            pt2current.y=-pt2current.x/tan(theta1) + p1/sin(theta1);
        }
        else
        {
            pt1current.y=0;
            pt1current.x=p1/cos(theta1);

            pt2current.y=img.size().height;
            pt2current.x=-pt2current.y/tan(theta1) + p1/cos(theta1);
        }

        vector<Vec2f>::iterator pos;

        for(pos=lines->begin();pos!=lines->end();pos++)
        {
            if(*current==*pos)
                continue;

            if(fabs((*pos)[0]-(*current)[0])<20 && fabs((*pos)[1]-(*current)[1])<CV_PI*10/180)
            {
                float p = (*pos)[0];
                float theta = (*pos)[1];

                Point pt1, pt2;
                if((*pos)[1]>CV_PI*45/180 && (*pos)[1]<CV_PI*135/180)
                {
                    pt1.x=0;
                    pt1.y = p/sin(theta);

                    pt2.x=img.size().width;
                    pt2.y=-pt2.x/tan(theta) + p/sin(theta);
                }

                else
                {
                    pt1.y=0;
                    pt1.x=p/cos(theta);

                    pt2.y=img.size().height;
                    pt2.x=-pt2.y/tan(theta) + p/cos(theta);
                }

                if(((double)(pt1.x-pt1current.x)*(pt1.x-pt1current.x) 
                    + (pt1.y-pt1current.y)*(pt1.y-pt1current.y)<64*64) 
                    && ((double)(pt2.x-pt2current.x)*(pt2.x-pt2current.x) + (pt2.y-pt2current.y)*(pt2.y-pt2current.y)<64*64))
                {
                    printf("Merging\n");
                    // Merge the two
                    (*current)[0] = ((*current)[0]+(*pos)[0])/2;
                    (*current)[1] = ((*current)[1]+(*pos)[1])/2;

                    (*pos)[0]=0;
                    (*pos)[1]=-100;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

example images:

[good image](http://postimg.org/image/c8brcd2r9/)

[bad image](http://postimg.org/image/92r5m5k51/)

for the bad image-this code works , but of course i need something more generic...

```
boarderLines.push_back(verticalLines[1]);
            boarderLines.push_back(verticalLines[verticalLines.size()-3]);

            boarderLines.push_back(horizontalLines[1]);
            boarderLines.push_back(horizontalLines[horizontalLines.size() -2 ]);
```

thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: bad image lines http://postimg.org/image/5x6jvy1it/

Comment: It's simple. You don't have King placed on the board!

Comment: A serious answer would be more helpful